# Differences between class declarations

Tags: delphi, class, type-declaration

There are many ways to declare a new class type:

1. `TMyClass1 = TObject;`
2. `TMyClass2 = type TObject;`
3. `TMyClass3 = class end;`
4. `TMyClass4 = class(TObject);`
5. `TMyClass5 = class(TObject) end;`

It's my understanding that class 3, 4 and 5 are descendants of `TObject`, but it's not clear how 1 and 2 differ, and what the differences between 3,4 and 5 are.

Are there any differences?

Comment: Version 4 is typically used for the well known "protected hack". I always prefer version 3 to version 5. Version 2 kind of defeats the purpose of OOP!

Comment: `TMyClass6 = Class;` - a forward class definition...

Comment: `TMyClass7 = Class of TMyClass6;` - a metaclass reference ...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

- `TMyClass1` is just an alias - a different name for `TObject`
- `TMyClass2` is a strongly typed alias for `TObject` (we call them "type'd types"); it's very unusual to use this with classes, though, normally you'd use this with e.g. `Pointer` to create a handle type or something (see e.g. how this is used in Windows.pas).
- `TMyClass3` is a class, implicitly descending from `TObject`, with no new members.
- `TMyClass4` is a class, explicitly descending from `TObject`, with no new members, using the concise syntax. More normally, this is used for marker classes, where the uniqueness of the class itself is the interesting thing - often used for `Exception` descendants
- `TMyClass5` is a class, explicitly descending from `TObject`, with no new members. The `TObject` in the declaration is redundant, but it doesn't harm anything to make it explicit.