# What's the difference between defining a class as TObject or just a class?

Tags: delphi, class, object, types, pascal

What is the difference between these two ways of defining a class?

```
TMyClass = class

end;

TMyObject = class(TObject)

end;
```

Obviously one derives from a `TObject` and the other is a class of its own. But what is the fundamental difference between using the two?

Comment: Why did you not simply read the documentation. There's no excuse for asking a question without reading the documentation. And since it's so trivially easy to find the relevant section, I can only conclude that you did not do it.

Comment: Thanks, @David, for pointing out how easy it is to find one line of text in such a massive set of documentation. Essentially nearly everything can be discovered by reading documentation.

Comment: Although the documentation is huge (some say not huge enough) this is one of the really basic informations you should know (or read the doc to know) dealing with OOP and Delphi

Comment: The language documentation is clearly laid out. The topic is called classes and objects. If you had looked you would have found it easily. If you don't know your way around the dcoumentation, you should take some time to learn your way around it. I regularly answer questions here by simply reading and linking to the docs. Can usually find the relevant section in a couple of minutes. It's really easy if you try.

Comment: While I'm all for curiosity, this seems to me like a typical question for the sake of asking and attention seeking, perhaps a reputation raising attempt but certainly not motivated by an actual development problem. So, therefor I downvoted

Comment: I agree with David, it's a trivial question, even googling your own title of the question yields the documentation on Classes and Objects as first result.

Comment: I'm voting for this question because of the second reason; *it is useful and clear* and because if someone Google this, they will be linked here.

Comment: Nice discussion about searching, existing documentation, etc. An actual search for https://www.google.com/search?q=difference+between+%22class(TObject)%22+and+%22class%22+delphi would have revealed  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086439/differences-between-class-declarations
Sometimes the answers at SO are more concise and clear than any Delphi documentation is. Which is OK: both have different objectives.

Comment: @jeroen In this instance, its hard to see how the docs could be more concise or clearer.

Comment: We disagree, but that's OK. I prefer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086439/differences-between-class-declarations over http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Classes_and_Objects as the former is more concise and clear for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no difference. Quote from the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Classes_and_Objects):

> If you omit (ancestorClass), then the new class inherits directly from the predefined System.TObject class.

Comment: Well technically "there is no difference" isn't 100% accurate - the difference is that if you omit `(TObject)` it results in cleaner code :D

Comment: I guess this comes down to preference, I don't think the code is cleaner when you omit the optional anchector. I like to see it there, I never omit it.

Comment: True, true, then technically "results in less code"

Comment: Well, the compiled code is the same in both cases and unless you enter into some "shortest possible source code solution" content, it shouldn't matter. Then again, some people are paid by LOC, and then using the anchestor declaration creatively can pay off, literally :)

Comment: Okay, okay, "results in less original source code" :)

Comment: Nope, `class(TObject)` does not pay more that just `class` ;-) Chinese coders paid by LoC are masters of arrays and loop unwinding ;-)

Comment: Fine "results in 9 less characters to your source code"

Comment: I find `class(TObject)` to be cleaner, because it indicates you have given thought about the ancestor.

Comment: So then you would write `I := I + 0` to document that you have thought about incrementing the variable? :)

Comment: Smasher: I don't use code browsing to look up where "0" is defined :-)  Btw, it maybe should be mentioned that it is possibly historic since TP didn't inherit always from tobject. (not single rooted class hierarchy)

Comment: @Smasher seriously: I think for assigning `I` to `I` with a certain increment in a series of assignments that have different increments: yes.
Code is all about intent, and for me the intent in a `class` declaration needs to describe the ancestor.